# How to extract the first non-blank cell data (numbers) and continue the extraction, first, second, third, etc from a column, and extract to a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icSJP.jpg) I need the formula to start looking from the top of the column list of revenues and find the first cell that has number data in it, and the second, third, forth and so on, until 60th. This data then needs to be displayed in a horizontal row. Month 1, Month 2, and so on.

In this case, it will put the number data from October into Month 1 on the row at the top. It should continue with November as Month 2.

I should mention, this starting point will change, This time is October, next time it can be any other month that will begin as Month 1

I've tried some code which worked initially but when I tried to move the reference cells to find my data, it stopped working. Been at this for 2 days, need help.

Thank you to all the smart folks out there...much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, here's a solution:

[image]

Cell F2: `{=INDEX($A$2:$A$38,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK($C$2:$C$38),0))}` *enter with ctrl+shift+enter*

Cell G2: `=F2+1` *drag it until the last column*

Cell F3: `=INDEX($B$2:$B$38,MATCH(F$2,$A$2:$A$38,0))` *drag it until the last column*

Cell F4: `=INDEX($C$2:$C$38,MATCH(F$2,$A$2:$A$38,0))` *drag it until the last column*

I'm assuming there are no blank cells after the first non-blank.

---

*Edit:* if there are zeros instead of blanks, use this on F2:

```
{=INDEX($A$2:$A$38,MATCH(FALSE,INDEX($C$2:$C$38=0,),0))}
```

Comment: Lucas, you nailed it. Excellent! It worked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the values in Jan-Sep are actually zeroes and the hyphen comes from a accounting style number format.

If the word *Month* in the green cell is B2 put this into the cell under *Month 1* and drag right.

```
=index(c:c, aggregate(15, 7, row($3:$99)/($c$3:$c$99>0), column(a:a)))
```